# When taking a screenshot using Unity's RenderTexture, the post-processing effects are not being applied

Tags: unity-game-engine, screenshot

Post-processed (On the Camera)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbYmG.png)

Not Post-processed (When taking a screen captrue)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVxV8.png)

The following code is for screen capture with an in-game camera at runtime.

1. Create render textures and assign newly created render textures to camera target textures
2. Coroutine - Run WaitForEndOfFrame
3. Camera Render
4. Create Texture2D to save to file path and run ReadPixels() and Apply()

```cs
 private static IEnumerator RecordFrame(RectTransform rectTransform = null, RawImage rawImage = null)
    {
        // Disable UI to hide
        TurnOffOtherCameras();

        // Save Texture in the Last Frame
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        CaptureScreenAndSave(rectTransform, rawImage);

        TurnOnOtherCameras();
    }


private static async UniTask<bool> CaptureScreenAndSave(RectTransform rectTransform = null, RawImage rawImage = null)
    {

...
                // This is the main ScreenCaptrue logic
        string totalPath = TotalPath;
        Texture2D screenTex = null;

        int pixelWidth, pixelHeight;
        pixelWidth = rectTransform == null ? _camera.pixelWidth : (int)rectTransform.rect.width;
        pixelHeight = rectTransform == null ? _camera.pixelHeight : (int)rectTransform.rect.height;

     
            var rt = new RenderTexture(pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);

            var prev = _camera.targetTexture;

            _camera.targetTexture = rt;
            _camera.Render();

            screenTex = new Texture2D(pixelWidth, pixelHeight, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
            RenderTexture.active = rt;

            Rect area = new Rect(0f, 0f, pixelWidth, pixelHeight);

            screenTex.ReadPixels(area, 0, 0);
            screenTex.Apply();

            _camera.targetTexture = prev;

            if (Directory.Exists(FolderPath) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);
            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(totalPath, screenTex.EncodeToPNG());

...

}
```

The reason why post-processing effects are not applied even when waiting for the last frame with a coroutine and WaitForEndOfFrame is quite intriguing. As far as I know, the rendering order is supposed to be camera rendering, scene rendering, and then the application of post-processing. Why might it not be working?

https://docs.unity3d.com/kr/2022.1/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Because the rendering pipeline is URP, I understand that it cannot be resolved using OnRenderImage.
Additionally, callbacks such as RenderPipelineManager.endCameraRendering and endFrameRendering didn't yield the desired post-processing results.

There is a ScreenCapture class supported by Unity Engine, and there is a way to solve it using this, but it was too buggy and resolution issue to use.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-capture-screenshot-with-post-processing.701432/

Instead of OnRenderImage, URP can use Scriptable RenderPass to implement it similar to OnRenderImage
If anyone is familiar with this and can provide insights, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, just an idea: If nothing helps you could try and implement a [Custom Effect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.3/manual/Writing-Custom-Effects.html) with `PostProcessEvent.AfterStack` which basically wouldn't be an actual effect but taking your screenshot if it is enabled (which would be only once and then deactivate itself - see `IsEnabledAndSupported`) .. you wouldn't go through the camera then but directly use `Blit` in order to copy over the current render image